# Custom list traversal and modification

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm traversing a two-dimensional list (my representation of a matrix) in an unusual order: counterclockwise around the outside starting with the top-left element.

I need to do this more than once, but each time I do it, I'd like to do something different with the values I encounter. The first time, I want to note down the values so that I can modify them. (I can't modify them in place.) The second time, I want to traverse the outside of the matrix and modify the values of the matrix as I go, perhaps getting my new values from some generator.

Is there a way I can abstract this traversal to a function and still achieve my goals? I was thinking that this traverse-edge function could take a function and a matrix and apply the function to each element on the edge of the matrix. However, the problems with this are two-fold. If I do this, I don't think I can modify the matrix that's given as an argument, and I can't yield the values one by one because yield isn't a function.

Edit: I want to rotate a matrix counterclockwise (not 90 degrees) where one rotation moves, for example, the top-left element down one spot. To accomplish this, I'm rotating one "level" (or shell) of the matrix at a time. So if I'm rotating the outermost level, I want to traverse it once to build a list which I can shift to the left, then I want to traverse the outermost level again to assign it those new values which I calculated.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want to do?

Comment: Simple answer, yes sou can abstract this to a function.  You just need to work out the logic and implement it in code.  Start small maybe try to work it out on paper first.

Comment: How large can the *matrix* get?  And do you need to *go around* the inner layers?

Answer (score 1):

Just create 4 loops, one for each side of the array, that counts through the values of the index that changes for that side.  For example, the first side, whose x index is always 0, could vary the y from 0 to n-2 (from the top-left corner to just shy of the bottom-left); repeat for the other sides.

Comment: But rather than writing these four loops several times, can I abstract them into one function?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two approaches you can take to solving your problem.

The first option is to create a function that returns an iterable of indexes into the matrix. Then you'd write your various passes over the matrix with `for` loops:

```
for i, j in matrix_border_index_gen(len(matrix), len(matrix[0])): # pass in dimensions
    # do something with matrix[i][j]
```

The other option is to write a function that works more like `map` that applies a given function to each appropriate value of the matrix in turn. If you sometimes need to replace the current values with new ones, I'd suggest doing that all the time (the times when you don't want to replace the value, you can just have your function return the previous value):

```
def func(value):
    # do stuff with value from matrix
    return new_value # new_value can be the same value, if you don't want to change it

matrix_border_map(func, matrix) # replace each value on border of matrix with func(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added a few lines of python 3 code here. It has the mirror function and a spiral iterator (not sure, if that's what you meant). No doc strings (sorry). It is readable though. Change print statement for python 2.

**EDIT : FIXED A BUG**

```
class Matrix():

    def __init__(self, rows=5, cols=5):
        self.cells = [[None for c in range(cols)] for r in range(rows)]

    def transpose(self):
        self.cells = list(map(list, zip(*self.cells)))

    def mirror(self):
        for row in self.cells:
            row.reverse()

    def invert(self):
        self.cells.reverse()

    def rotate(self, clockwise=True):
        self.transpose()
        self.mirror() if clockwise else self.invert()

    def iter_spiral(self, grid=None):
        grid = grid or self.cells
        next_grid = []
        for cell in reversed(grid[0]):
            yield cell
        for row in grid[1:-1]:
            yield row[0]
            next_grid.append(row[1:-1])
        if len(grid) > 1:
            for cell in grid[-1]:
                yield cell
        for row in reversed(grid[1:-1]):
            yield row[-1]
        if next_grid:
            for cell in self.iter_spiral(grid=next_grid):
                yield cell

    def show(self):
        for row in self.cells:
            print(row)

def test_matrix():
    m = Matrix()
    m.cells = [[1,2,3,4],
               [5,6,7,8],
               [9,10,11,12],
               [13,14,15,16]]
    print("We expect the spiral to be:", "4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 9, 13, 14, 15, 16, 12, 8, 7, 6, 10, 11", sep='\n')
    print("What the iterator yields:")
    for cell in m.iter_spiral():
        print(cell, end=', ')
    print("\nThe matrix looks like this:")
    m.show()
    print("Now this is how it looks rotated 90 deg clockwise")
    m.rotate()
    m.show()
    print("Now we'll rotate it back")
    m.rotate(clockwise=False)
    m.show()
    print("Now we'll transpose it")
    m.transpose()
    m.show()
    print("Inverting the above")
    m.invert()
    m.show()
    print("Mirroring the above")
    m.mirror()
    m.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_matrix()
```

This is the output:

```
We expect the spiral to be:
4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 9, 13, 14, 15, 16, 12, 8, 7, 6, 10, 11
What the iterator yields:
4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 9, 13, 14, 15, 16, 12, 8, 7, 6, 10, 11, 
The matrix looks like this:
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[9, 10, 11, 12]
[13, 14, 15, 16]
Now this is how it looks rotated 90 deg clockwise
[13, 9, 5, 1]
[14, 10, 6, 2]
[15, 11, 7, 3]
[16, 12, 8, 4]
Now we'll rotate it back
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[9, 10, 11, 12]
[13, 14, 15, 16]
Now we'll transpose it
[1, 5, 9, 13]
[2, 6, 10, 14]
[3, 7, 11, 15]
[4, 8, 12, 16]
Inverting the above
[4, 8, 12, 16]
[3, 7, 11, 15]
[2, 6, 10, 14]
[1, 5, 9, 13]
Mirroring the above
[16, 12, 8, 4]
[15, 11, 7, 3]
[14, 10, 6, 2]
[13, 9, 5, 1]
```

Comment: How about adding data to the cells?

Comment: @wwii You can add a `populate` function which I haven't.

Comment: Sounds like the OP wants to *go around the edge*, not spiral in.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with [generator functions](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators). They can be used to create iterators over which we can iterate. An Example of a generator function -

```
def genfunc():
    i = 0
    while i < 10:
            yield i
            i = i + 1

>>> for x in genfunc():
...     print(x)
...
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

When calling the generator function, it returns a generator object -

```
>>> genfunc()
<generator object genfunc at 0x00553AD0>
```

It does not start going over the function at that point. When you start iterating over the generator object, calling for its first element, it starts going over the function, untill it reaches the first yield statement, and at that point it returns the value (in above case, it returns value of `i`) . And it also saves the state of the function at that point (that is it saves at what point the execution was when the value was yielded, what were the values for the variables in the local namespace, etc).

Then when it tries to get the next value, again execution starts from where it stopped last time, till it again yield another value. And this continues on.